# Numpy - show decimal values in array results

Tags: python, numpy

how do I calculate that an array of python numpy or me of all the calculate decimals and not skip like.

```
>> A = numpy.array ([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]).

>> C = numpy.array ([[7,8,9], [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]).

>> A / C

array ([[0, 0, 0],
       [4, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

but in the first vector would not have to be given to absolute zero `[0.143, 0.250, 0.333]`

Comment: This is an English speaking forum. Your title needs editing to be in English.

Comment: Hola Ricardo, el título en inglés por favor. :-)

Comment: I have no idea what the question is about, I hope I translated correctly :)

Comment: hello, excuse was a mistake not happen again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid integer division, use `numpy.true_divide(A,C)`. You can also put `from __future__ import division` at the top of the file to default to this behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Try converting one of the arrays `A` or `C` into an array of floats.  For instance:

```
A = A * 1.0
```

Then the division will be floating point division.

Comment: THANK YOU. I've been struggling with this for *hours*.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy arrays may have different types. You may also create a float array, it will always divide correctly:

```
>>> A = numpy.array ([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], dtype=float)
>>> A/2
array([[ 0.5,  1. ,  1.5],
       [ 2. ,  2.5,  3. ],
       [ 3.5,  4. ,  4.5]])
```

Notice the `dtype=` argument to `numpy.array`